# ResourceBundleMessageSource setBaseName method allows prefix "file"?

Tags: spring, properties, internationalization

trying from a junit test to set a basename for ResourceBundleMessageSource spring class, when the test tries to get a message, I get the following "no message found under key.....". I have the next configuration below for a test. MessageSourceHolder is a static class to hold the messageSource. Is there something wrong with the setBasename parameter?. Is not allowed to use prefix "file"?. I do have a message.properties file under "src/main/resources/i18n".

```
   AbstractResourceBasedMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
   messageSource.setBasename("file:src/main/resources/i18n/messages");
   messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
   MessageSourceHolder.setMessageSource(messageSource);
```

If I do this, it works:

```
    File file = Paths.get("src/main/resources/i18n/messages.properties").toFile();
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new FileReader(file));        
    
    AbstractResourceBasedMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setCommonMessages(properties);
    MessageSourceHolder.setMessageSource(messageSource);
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in the ResourceBundleMessageSource class documentation that says:

> The basenames follow ResourceBundle conventions: essentially, a
> fully-qualified classpath location

So it does not allow the prefix file. The class ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource is meant to allow prefixes because it follows the Resource conventions.